# Spark -Scala - Convert CSV file to custom object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to convert csv data to custom object in spark. Below are my code snippet

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val citiData = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(filePath) // removing header,and applying schema

    //citiData.describe().show()
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val s: Dataset[CityData] = citiData.as[CityData]

  }
  //Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
  case class CityData(processingDate: java.util.Date, Open: Double, High: Double, Low: Double, Volume: Double)
```

Sample DataSet:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2006-01-03,490.0,493.8,481.1,492.9,1537660
2006-01-04,488.6,491.0,483.5,483.8,1871020
2006-01-05,484.4,487.8,484.0,486.2,1143160
2006-01-06,488.8,489.0,482.0,486.2,1370250
```

i have changed to case class CityData input param type to String , then it is causing "cannot resolve '`processingDate`' given input columns: [Volume, Close, High, Date, Low, Open];"  exception.

1. How can i create custom object
2. Another tricky here convert to Date object

How can i do ? please share your ideas.

Comment: After did some research , changed my dataset header "Date" to MyDate. and changed my case class  "case class CityData(MyDate: Date, Open: String, High: String, Low: String, Volume: String)" . Now how can i change to original data type like date ,double and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if you do not set option `header` to true, Spark will read columns with `String` type. With option `header`, you can see;

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv("pathToFile")
df.printSchema
//Prints
root
|-- Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- Open: double (nullable = true)
|-- High: double (nullable = true)
|-- Low: double (nullable = true)
|-- Close: double (nullable = true)
|-- Volume: integer (nullable = true)
```

If you try to convert rows into `CityData`, you will get the following error;

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.util.Date`

This means, you cannot convert `TimestampType` directly into `java.util.Date`. Here is the type mappings;

- TimestampType => java.sql.Timestamp
- DateType => java.sql.Date

After changing type of `processingDate` from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Timestamp`, you will still get an error which says `cannot resolve 'processingDate'`. You also need to change name of the field `processingDate` to `Date` in `CityData`. then you can convert your data set into `Dataset[CityData]` by using `df.as[CityData]`. I hope it helps!

Comment: How can i print list of value from open column using select.

Comment: Do you want to select Open column after converting rows into CityData?

Comment: Yes.. is it possible

Comment: Sure, since you have CityData as rows, you can use map function on this RDD to select only Open column. It is quite same with applying map operations on Scala list.